# In c++ is a linear sort the same meaning/thing as a insertion sort

Tags: c++

I have an exam tomorrow and i'm trying to learn  what a linear sort looks like but when I look it up on google I get insertion sort is it the same thing?

Comment: My understanding is that sorting algorithms are not based on the language.  An insert sort and binary-tree sort don't depend on the language and have different Big-O ratings (which are not calculated using a specific language).

Comment: I have never heard of a "linear sort". In general it is not possible to sort a collection with linear time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

All that the C++ standard guarantees is that `std::sort` is O(N·log(N).

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't the same. There is currently *no* such thing as linear sort. The best sorting runtime is logarithmic `O(N log N)` (examples: quicksort, mergesort) , and insertion sort does sorting in quadratic `O(N^2)` time.

However, what insertion sort *does* in linear time, is each insertion stage. When you take an element from the array, you compare it with *each* element of the array until you find a matching slot, and then insert it, thus the  worst-case linear `O(N)` insertion time.